# PyCharm: Typedef hint for function from pre-existing method's hint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

#### Introduction

Assuming following code:

```
import typing


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, l_key: str = "1234"):
        self.key = l_key

    def get_key(self) -> str:
        return self.key


dictOfFoos = typing.Dict[typing.get_type_hints(Foo.get_key)['return'], Foo]


def test_return() -> dictOfFoos:
    test = dict()
    test["123"] = Foo()
    return test


test_return()

print("0 " + str(type(Foo().key)))
print("1 " + str(typing.get_type_hints(Foo.get_key)['return']))
print("2 " + str(typing.get_type_hints(test_return)['return']))
```

Output is as follows:

```
0 <class 'str'>
1 <class 'str'>
2 typing.Dict[str, __main__.Foo]
```

Now when I press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to display "Quick documentation" following tooltips are displayed.

Hint for return value from `test_run()` function:

[image]

Hint for `test_run()` function:

[image]

I do understand that IDE do not run `typing.get_type_hints(Foo.key)['return']` to get type of return type from `Foo.key` method as this is run only in runtime.

#### Problem

Is there any way to define type hint which is based on hint from method in class assuming that `Foo.key` could change in the future?
Basically to have hint like:

`def test_run() -> Dict[str, Foo]`

Comment: `def key(self): return self.key()` is not going to do what you think.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you are right thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's not really clear from the title and description what you are trying to do; since the code doesn't do what you want it to do, that also isn't helping much. Can you please [edit] the question to clarify what your goal is? Am I reading this correctly that you want to define a type hint based on the type hint of a pre-existing method/function? Can you rewrite the original method/function, or do you have to work with it as-is?

Comment: The question was edited Mar 25 at 13:48 after @user2357112supportsMonica pointed out that I returned `self.key()` instead of `self.key`, but that does not change context of the question. Question is about type hints so basically rest of the code is redundant.
@MisterMiyagi you do understand question correctly, I would like to have type hints based on the pre-existing method in class Foo.
Basically: `Foo.key()` has type hint defined to `str`, and I would like that `dictOfFoos`  discovers that type and shows it correctly 2nd print, instead of "Any" as it is presented on the screen shot.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've edited title I hope it's more self-explanatory.

Comment: Please also clarify whether you can edit Foo.key. That is very important to decide whether the clean solution would work. I assume "pre-existing method" implies no, but it is not entirely clear.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that is the point, you are not suppose to know what type of method `Foo.key()` is, and you are not suppose to assume anything about it. Only one thing what you want is to get type of the return's type hint without running `dictOfFoos = typing.Dict[typing.get_type_hints(Foo.key)['return'], Foo]`. I'm looking for the way, how to achive same result without running python code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in question (I think) I clearly presented what is the result for `dictOfFoos = typing.Dict[typing.get_type_hints(Foo.key)['return'], Foo]` is which is how I am expecting pyCharm to handle it to, but as pyCharm does handles it differently I'm asking about any ideas how to get him to parse it properly.

Comment: Sorry for being so pedantic, it is just that there are some easy ways to do this in practical usage; I am trying to work out whether that just got lost when you created the example. For example, a practical use-case would be that ``test_return`` *receives* some ``Foo``(s) and one could match a protocol on that. Another use-case would be that ``test_return`` constructs some and ``Foo``(s) and returns their ``foo.get_key(): foo`` pairs which one could just infer. Compare Pycharm's type inference for just ``def test_return(): foo = Foo(); return {foo.get_key(): foo}``.

Comment: Don't be sorry I really appreciate your interest and all the comments. Your idea is ingenious and very simple I like that, but I was looking for something a bit different as I'm working on "interfacing" some classes in python :) Because of you pinging me about the code I found solution myself which is embarrassingly simple. Will give an answer soon, and I will mention yours idea if that's fine with you. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MisterMiyagi had great and easy solution:

```
def test_return_v2():
    foo = Foo()
    return {foo.get_key(): foo}
```

Which generated correct hint:

[image]

But I was looking specifically for type hint, as I wanted to write interface methods that do not have implementation but defines method to be overwritten in inherited classes (what of course I should mention in question, sorry):

```
def get_key(self) -> str:
    pass
```

It's enough to declare type with `type` function:

```
dictOfFoos2 = typing.Dict[type(Foo.get_key()), Foo]


def test_return_v3() -> dictOfFoos2:
    test = dict()
    test["123"] = Foo()
    return test
```

[image]